# What Windows tools can access and decrypt Mac hard drives?

Tags: windows, encryption, hard-disk, macos, filesystems

In my project, I have some encrypted Mac hard drives (apfs), and I am required to access the data from some Windows 10 machine.

I tried to use HFSexplorer to extract all possible partitions. But most of the time, I got "Invalid HFS type ... Detected type (UNKNOWN)" error, and an empty folder "Boot OS X".

Could anyone provide me any guidance on this? Thanks.

I checked these HD on my MacOS, and I can successfully access data after providing the correct passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will first need a tool that can read APFS.

Older HFS+ tools will not be able to read APFS. Paragon has one [though it's a bit expensive] - [APFS for Windows](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/apfs-windows/)

It can also handle encrypted volumes, as read-only.